# Trying to workout the problem in this C# code for Arithmetic Sequence using iteration and recursion

Tags: c#

This is for a college assignment but I cannot workout what I'm doing wrong. I am new to programming and any help would really be appreciated as this assignment is due in 8 hours.

There is an error on `int sum=0` where it says

> "The variable sum is assigned but its value is never used". It also says the same for i and ln. What can I do to solve this issue>

```
using System;  
public class arithmeticSequence
{  
    public static void Main()
     {

      Console.Write("\n\n");    
      Console.Write("------------------------------------------------------------");
      Console.Write("\n\n");    
      Console.Write("Calculates the sum of n numbers in an arithmetic sequence:\n");
      Console.Write("\n\n");    
      Console.Write("------------------------------------------------------------");
      Console.Write("\n\n");    

      int x,d,n,i,ln; //x = starting number, n = number of items, d = difference
      int sum=0;


      Console.Write("Please enter the starting number (x): ");
x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  

      Console.Write("Please enter the number of items (n): ");
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  

      Console.Write("Please enter the common difference (d): ");
d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  

      Console.WriteLine("Sum of {x} to {d} numbers is {SumByIteration(x, d, n, i, ln, sum)}");
Console.WriteLine("Sum of {x} to {d} numbers is {SumByRecursion(i, ln, x, n, d, sum)}");

}

static int SumByIteration(int x, int d, int n, int i, int ln, int sum){
     sum = ( n * ( 2 * x + ( n -1 ) * d ) )/ 2;
     ln = x + (n-1) * d;
     Console.Write("\nThe Sum of the  A.P. series are : \n");

     for(i=x;i<=ln; i= i + d ){
     if (i != ln)
         Console.Write("{0} + ",i);
     else
         Console.Write("{0} = {1} \n\n",i,sum);
     }return sum;
}

static int SumByRecursion(int i, int ln, int x, int n, int d, int sum){
    i = x;
    for (x = 1; x < n; x++)
    {
      ln = d + ln + i;
      i = 0;
      sum = sum + ln;

    }
    return sum;

    }

}
```

Comment: have you thought about what the message could *mean*? and about the difference between "error" and "warning"?

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Answer (score 1):

> There is an error on "int sum=0" where it says "The variable sum is assigned but its value is never used". It also says the same for i and ln. What can I do to solve this issue>

There is no error, but there is likely a warning. As the warning indicates, you have declared variables inside of your main method that your code is not using. To solve this warning, remove sum, i, and ln declarations ... or start using them for whatever purpose you originally intended.

Your code currently manually does the sum of the operations in a console writeline, as opposed to

```
sum = SumByIteration(x, d, n, i, ln, sum);
```

You are also passing un-initialized values (i, ln) to your Sum operations (there is no code assignment in main) and an unnecessary sum. You currently only set values for x, d, and n in main.

Comment: This really helped, thanks a lot. SumByIteration is now working for me however SumByRecursion is not displaying in the final result. Would you have any tips on how I could fix my code to show the final step?

Answer (score 0):

First things first you are not using `String Interpolation` correctly so your method `SumByIteration` and `SumByRecursion` are never called. You are missing the `$` in the begainning.

Instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("Sum of {x} to {d} numbers is {SumByIteration(x, d, n, i, ln, sum)}");
Console.WriteLine("Sum of {x} to {d} numbers is {SumByRecursion(i, ln, x, n, d, sum)}");
```

Use `$`

```
Console.WriteLine($"Sum of {x} to {d} numbers is {SumByIteration(x, d, n, i, ln, sum)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Sum of {x} to {d} numbers is {SumByRecursion(i, ln, x, n, d, sum)}");
```

In response to your error `The variable sum is assigned but its value is never used`

You don't seem to be initialising your variables?

```
int x, d, n, i, ln; //x = starting number, n = number of items, d = difference
int sum = 0;
```

Do you see the problem? you need to initialise them like `int x = 0`.

Perhaps like this:

```
const int i = 0; //x = starting number, n = number of items, d = difference
const int ln = 0; //x = starting number, n = number of items, d = difference
const int sum = 0;

Console.Write("Please enter the starting number (x): ");
var x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Please enter the number of items (n): ");
var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Please enter the common difference (d): ");
var d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

You program only seems to set the value of `z,d,n`? Where do you set `i,ln,sum`?

Also you need to handle `null reference exceptions` in `int.Parse()`

Comment: This really helped, thanks a lot. SumByIteration is now working for me however SumByRecursion is not displaying in the final result. Would you have any tips on how I could fix my code to show the final step?